# Make object array in php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, object, foreach

i used to do object arrays in javascript or java but i feel like it doesn't work in php.

In JS i will do roughly :

```js
    var users = [];
    var user_password = [{
        user : "username1",
        pass : "password"
    }, {
        user : "username2",
        pass : "password"
    }, {
        user : "username3",
        pass : "password"
    }]
    
    user_password.forEach(anUser => {
        var user = {
            username: anUser.user,
            password: anUser.pass
        }
        users.push(user);
    });    
    
    return users;
    
    // return : [{
    //     username : "username1",
    //     password : "password"
    // }, {
    //     username : "username2",
    //     password : "password"
    // }, {
    //     username : "username3",
    //     password : "password"
    // }]
```

But when i make this in PHP :

```php
    $yourls_user_passwords = [
      'projet@gmail.com' => 'phpass:!2a!08!dJOIkAq/TJZIpwYHcqwf4uDwcraOJDIGIDSOJGOIDSJGOIJSDOIGJ.og2' /* Password encrypted by YOURLS */ ,
        'username6@gmail.com' => 'phpass:!2a!08!9Fqoufb2b70Oq6xsRfCKu.q7vxxMdSLxWXVbZV2C1EBAJcAPn2Ldy' /* Password encrypted by YOURLS */ ,
        'username@gmail.com' => 'phpass:!2a!08!DJpKEAhWtrrPrQqi9uOSreUM1ZROFsQUr5fYiq7ADwa/3EehxjgKO' /* Password encrypted by YOURLS */ ,
        // You can have one or more 'login'=>'password' lines
    ];
    
    // roles of different users
    $amp_role_assignment = array(
        'administrator' => array(
            'projet@gmail.com',
            // add other administrator
        ),
        'editor' => array(
            // add other editor
        ),
        'contributor' => array(
            'username6@gmail.com',
            'username@gmail.com',
            // add other contributor
        ),
    );

    $users = array();

    foreach ($yourls_user_passwords as $username => $password) {
        $anUser = (object)[];
        foreach ($amp_role_assignment as $role => $users) {
            foreach ($users as $user){
                if ($user == $username) {
                    $anUser->username = $username;
                    $anUser->role = $role;
                }
            }
        }
        var_dump("</br>USER OBJECT</br>");
        var_dump($anUser);
        $users[] = $anUser;
    }
    var_dump("</br></br>USERS ELEMENT 1</br>");
    var_dump($users[0]);
```

[image: var_dump]

When I display the elements one by one before adding them to my user array it does display each object one by one to me but when I display them directly with their index it doesn't work.

I don't understand, is there something wrong with my code? Thank you very much by advance !

Comment: `foreach ($amp_role_assignment as $role => $users)` - you are overwriting your existing `$users = array();` here at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, it's work ! Good day to you !